# Creating multiple pngs with ImageMagick causes slow desktop

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, imagemagick

I am running Linux Mint 17, Cinnamon 2.4.8

Hello, I am using ImageMagick to create large 500+ png images.

This causes Cinnamon to go very slow.

I would understand if Cinnamon is slow **WHILE** I am rendering many images, however, Cinnamon is really slow even **AFTER** the renders are complete.

The only way to remedy this is to do a reboot, but I would really like another solution if possible.

**Command `free` BEFORE render**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16384584    1066072   15318512      20212      61948     407592
-/+ buffers/cache:     596532   15788052
Swap:     16727036          0   16727036
```

**Command `free` DURING render**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16384584    1230524   15154060      21148      69540     457700
-/+ buffers/cache:     703284   15681300
Swap:     16727036          0   16727036
```

**Command `free` AFTER render**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16384584    1263932   15120652      20760      70416     460352
-/+ buffers/cache:     733164   15651420
Swap:     16727036          0   16727036
```

Comment: Check the output of `free` before and after running the image processing job. Also check `top` when your system is slow: is the CPU busy, and if so, what processes are keeping it (press `P` to sort processes by CPU usage time)?

Comment: Hello, I updated my question with the output of `free`. There is nothing that seems to be related to imagemagick from my `top` output

Comment: Before and after. What's interesting is the difference. And the top output is relevant whether there's anything IM-related — how much CPU is used, and by what process if not IM?

Comment: @Gilles there updated sorry about that. It's weird, the used is even higher even after the render. It's pretty weird that it increases after the process is completed

Comment: By the way, did you check for temporary files left over in a tmpfs filesystem, which shivams already suggested?

Comment: No I found nothing that seemed to be in relation to ImageMagick

Answer (score 1):

#### Memory Issue

This is most probably a memory issue.

One thing to do is to limit the memory usage of `imagemagick`. As mentioned here: [-limit type value](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#limit), you can limit your usage using these options:

```
-limit memory 512MiB -limit map 512MiB
```

Further, as you're saying that it is slow even **AFTER** imagemagick is run, in that case look for some ghost processes left over by imagemagick which are making it not release the RAM. And kill those processes.

```
ps aux | grep convert    #assuming you used convert
```

#### Another Possibility : Disk full due to temporary files

Check your `/tmp` directory or some other directory it might be storing its temporary files and see if that corresponding to it has space or not. That might be a probably reason. Reboot usually deletes temp files and relieves space.

Comment: Do you think lowering the memory will make my renders slower? The render speed is a bit important to me.
I did get the following from `ps aux | grep convert` **eric     21358  0.0  0.0  11748  2156 pts/2    S+   20:38   0:00 grep --colour=auto convert** but I think it's from the grep command itself.
I found nothing in /tmp that seemed to correlate with ImageMagick.

Comment: which tool from `imagemagick` are you using?

Comment: convert and identify

Comment: @TuxForLife Could you give the commands you are using so that I can reproduce the problem on my desktop on some dummy images. I am on Mint 17.1 but I'm using Mate instead of Cinnamon. Hopefully the problem would be reproduced and some solution could be found.

Comment: Hey @shivams, try this `mkdir TuxTest ; for num in {1..500} ; do convert -background none -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf -pointsize 4000 label:"$num" TuxTest/TEST$num.png ; done`

Comment: @TuxForLife I saw your updated question with the `free` command's output. Clearly, RAM is not is not issue.

Comment: @TuxForLife I also tried your command inside Mint 17.1 Mate (in a virtual machine). It didn't slow down during or after rendering. Now, the only difference between mine and your setup is : 1) I am on Mate instead of Cinnamon, and 2) I have no graphics card driver inside virtual machine. So, either it's some problem with your graphics card or problem with Cinnamon.

Comment: I believe it is just plain cinnamon's fault, looking at this post, I believe it is a bug from cinnamon. It gets really annoying after a while :(

Comment: @TuxForLife You could install mate desktop and see if the problem occurs their also. Just do `sudo apt-get install mate-desktop`.

Comment: I updated to the NVIDIA 352.09 driver today, and I believe it has been the ultimate remedy!

Comment: Okay. So, did updating NVIDIA driver fix your problem finally? If yes, then good to hear :)